# More Efficient Way to Grab the Latest Value based off a composite index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called SAMPLE_TABLE that has the following columns, with CAR_TYPE, COLOR and CAR_BRAND making up the composite index.

```
 VALUE_ID      VALUE      CAR_TYPE     COLOR     SUBMIT_DT      CAR_BRAND
   1            10        Sedan        Blue      3/7/2019       Ford
   2            70        Sedan        Blue      3/6/2019       Ford
   3            20        Sedan        Blue      3/5/2019       Ford
   4            77         SUV         Red       3/7/2019       Volvo
   5           100         SUV         Red       3/1/2019       Volvo
```

Is there a way I can write a more efficient way to query for the Value correlated to the LATEST `SUBMIT_DT`? In the future, the TABLE will have millions of rows of data, so I will need to find a query with the lowest run-time/cost that can query.

For example, below is what I would want in my result set when querying for a Blue Ford Sedan:

```
 VALUE
 10
```

Below is what I have thus far:

```
 SELECT value 
   FROM (
          SELECT *
            FROM TABLE
           WHERE CAR_TYPE = rCar_Type
             AND COLOR = rColor
             AND CAR_BRAND = rCar_Brand
            ORDER by submit_dt desc
        )
   WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Is this inefficient?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A key cannot accept duplicate values -- by definition. In your case, the first, second, and third rows have the same value for the composite key.

Comment: I am looking for the value with the LATEST submit_DT correlated to that composite key as stated here: "Is there a way I can write a more efficient way to query for the Value correlated to the LATEST SUBMIT_DT?"

Comment: I don't know which query is the most efficient. You've already got some answers. Use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to see which one costs less. Your query is okay and probably as fast as all the others. You are using a method, though, where Oracle violates the SQL standard. Subqueries are considered unordered, but Oracle still support their old method of picking a particular row with rownum from an ordered subquery. Nowadays you should use another method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow... there are a lot of answers already, but I think some of them missed what I think is the point of your question.

You are going to have millions rows in your table and your composite index on (CAR_TYPE, COLOR, CAR_BRAND) will not be very selective.  You are looking for a way to get the one row having the last SUBMIT_DT for a given entry in your composite index without having to read through ALL of the matches from that index.

**Answer: add `SUBMIT_DT DESC` to your composite index**

Let's set up a test:

```
create table matt_objects as select * from dba_objects;

-- This is our analog of your composite index
create index matt_objects_n1 on matt_objects ( object_type, owner );

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'MATT_OBJECTS');
```

Now, let's autotrace this statement:

```
select object_name
from   matt_objects
where  object_type = 'TABLE'
and    owner = 'INV'
order by last_ddl_time desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Id  | Operation                             | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                 |     1 |    88 |    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
> |*  1 |  VIEW                                 |                 |     1 |    88 |    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
> |*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK             |                 |   162 |  7290 |    17   (6)| 00:00:01 |
> |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| MATT_OBJECTS    |   162 |  7290 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> |*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | MATT_OBJECTS_N1 |   162 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
> ---------------------------------------------------
>
>    1 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=1)
>    2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY INTERNAL_FUNCTION("LAST_DDL_TIME") DESC )<=1)
>    4 - access("OBJECT_TYPE"='TABLE' AND "OWNER"='INV')
> ```

**Result (from autotrace): 72 consistent read buffer gets**

Now, let's replace your composite index with one that will help us out more:

```
drop index matt_objects_n1;

create index matt_objects_n1 on matt_objects ( object_type, owner, last_ddl_time desc );

exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user,'MATT_OBJECTS');
```

.. and let's autotrace that same statement again:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                 |     1 |    88 |    54   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                 |                 |     1 |    88 |    54   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   VIEW                         |                 |     1 |    88 |    53   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |                 |   162 |  7290 |    53   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MATT_OBJECTS    |   162 |  7290 |    53   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | MATT_OBJECTS_N1 |   162 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("from$_subquery$_002"."rowlimit_$$_rownumber"<=1)
   3 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SYS_OP_DESCEND("LAST_DDL_TIME"))<=1)
   5 - access("OBJECT_TYPE"='TABLE' AND "OWNER"='INV')
```

**Result (from autotrace): 5 consistent read gets**

That index helped a lot.  Notice the plan is different?  'WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK' has been replaced by 'WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY'.  With the index already sorted the way you want (in descending order), Oracle knows it can read the index rows in order and stop after the first one -- completing the query with much less effort.

It's interesting to note that the cost of the 2nd query is higher than the cost of the 1st query, even though the performance of the 2nd query is more than 10 times better.  It just goes to show you that "cost" is an estimate and should taken with a grain of salt sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, query you wrote can't exactly be called "inefficient" but "useless" in this context as it'll return one, *random* row. You're probably missing `ORDER BY` in a subquery.

Anyway: see how this behaves:

```
select value
  from (select row_number() over (partition by car_type, color, car_brand
                                  order by submit_dt desc) rn,
               value
        from sample_table
        where car_type = rcar_type
          and color = rcolor
          and car_brand = rcar_brand
       )
where rn = 1;
```

Don't forget to create index on columns used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It does, @TheImpaler? How do you know? As you said (in a comment below the question), those rows share the same values for columns that make that "composite key", so - what kind of a "key" is it? It isn't a primary key, it isn't a unique key either as both can't be created on such data. I'm not saying that you're wrong, just that I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: I forgot to add the order by clause, had to update my question :)

Comment: @JohnWick Downvoted because in your wording you are confusing the concept of "key" with the concept of "index". As this question is phrased it's of little value to any other user, or to StackOverflow. If you fix it, I'll be happy to remove my down vote.

Comment: Ok i'll fix it , point taken. I guess I was confused because I was ultimately trying to load a target table with a composite key composed of those three columns, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

I guess you meant "index" instead of "key" in your question. If that's the case, then I would create the index:

```
create index ix1 on sample_table (car_type, color, car_brand, submit_dt);
```

Then the following query will be instantaneous, since it won't read the heap:

```
select max(submit_dt)
from sample_table
where CAR_TYPE = rCar_Type
  and COLOR = rColor
  and CAR_BRAND = rCar_Brand
```

Comment: thanks. I also need the VALUE from that MAX(submit_dt) too :(

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the last value per `car_type`, `color`, `car_brand`. Oracle offers `KEEP LAST` for this:

```
SELECT MAX(value) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY submit_dt)
  FROM table
 WHERE car_type = :rcar_type
   AND color = :rcolor
   AND car_brand = :rcar_brand;
```

Comment: Don't you mean FIRST_VALUE() here?

Comment: @Hogan: No, I don't. `FIRST_VALUE` is an analytic function (i.e. it only works per row with an `OVER` clause). We need an aggregation function instead.

Comment: I don't understand, you are not using group by why is there a need for an aggregation function

Comment: @Hogan: Because the query shall return **one** row. It aggregates over the rows for the given `car_type` + `color` + `car_brand` and returns their latest value.

Comment: That is what First_Value does too

Comment: @Hogan: No. `FIRST_VALUE` is an **analytic function**. It doesn't aggregate the three rows to one, it keeps the three rows. You do know the difference between aggregation (e.g. `COUNT(*)`) and analytic functions (e.g. `COUNT(*) OVER()`), don't you? Here is the docs where they say explicitly that the function is analytic, and the syntax diagram shows the obligatory `OVER` clause: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions075.htm#SQLRF00642

Comment: max without a group by does the same thing -- you don't have a group by or distinct in the example above -- maybe this is where the confusion lies.

Comment: @Hogan: I don't know where your confusion lies. I don't know what it is you don't understand. My query results in one row, because it aggregates the rows. Yes, `MAX` without an `OVER` clause is one example for an aggregation function. A `GROUP BY` clause would lead to one result row per group. And an analytic function like `FIRST_VALUE OVER` or `MAX OVER` doesn't reduce the rows at all. In order to get that one value we are after, we want an aggregation without `GROUP BY` here.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `FETCH FIRST`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE CAR_TYPE = rCar_Type
  AND COLOR = rColor
  AND CAR_BRAND = rCar_Brand
ORDER BY submit_dt DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

If your version of the Database is `12c`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number to solve this problem.

For example

```
SELECT x.value 
FROM (
  SELECT VALUE, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CAR_TYPE, CAR_COLOR, CAR_BRAND ORDER BY SUBMIT_DATE DESC) AS RN
  FROM table
) x
WHERE x.RN = 1
```